Riverpod 2.x.x My form field reset when executing ref.read
When state has change text form field also reset in riverpod
for example, I am typing some on form field and then change my theme to dark/light via ref.read after that the form field is reset or back to empty.
 return Builder(
        key: loginBuilderKey,
        builder: (context) {
          return AdaptiveScaffold(
            fab: FloatingActionButton.small(
              foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
              onPressed: () {
                ref.read(appThemeModeProvider.notifier).setThemeMode(
                    isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);

                ref.invalidate(appThemeModeProvider);
              },
              child: const Icon(LucideIcons.sun),
            ),
            portrait: const PortraitView(),
            landscape: const LandscapeView(),
          );
        });

my PortraitView and LandscapeView have form_field
 Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final listCredentials = ref.watch(userLoginDataProvider);
    final isDarkMode = ref.watch(appThemeModeProvider
        .select((value) => value.valueOrNull == ThemeMode.dark));
    var emailCtrl = useTextEditingController();
    var passwordCtrl = useTextEditingController();
    var formController = useFormController();
    var passwordVisibility = useState(false);
    final passwordFocus = FocusNode();
    final emailFocus = FocusNode();

    return Form(
      key: formController.formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            controller: emailCtrl,
            focusNode: emailFocus,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            onTapOutside: (e) {
              emailFocus.unfocus();
            },
            //enabled: !loginPageData.loading,
            // autofocus: true,
            onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
              //FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordFocus);
            },
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                return 'Email is required!';
              }

              bool emailValid = RegExp(
                      r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                  .hasMatch(value);
              if (!emailValid) {
                return "The email address format is incorrect.";
              }

              return null;
            },
            cursorColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                  borderSide:
                      BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor)),
              labelText: 'Email',
              floatingLabelStyle: rubikMedium.copyWith(
                  color: isDarkMode
                      ? Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight
                      : Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              labelStyle: rubikMedium,
              fillColor: Colors.transparent,
              filled: true,
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: isDarkMode
                        ? Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight
                        : Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              ),
              suffixIcon: kDebugMode
                  ? listCredentials.when(
                      data: (users) {
                        return users.isEmpty
                            ? const SizedBox.shrink()
                            : IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  showUserSelectionDialog(users);
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(LucideIcons.user),
                              );
                      },
                      error: (e, s) {
                        return null;
                      },
                      loading: () => const SizedBox.shrink(),
                    )
                  : null,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          TextFormField(
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            controller: passwordCtrl,
            obscureText: !passwordVisibility.value,
            focusNode: passwordFocus,
            onTapOutside: (e) {
              passwordFocus.unfocus();
            },
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                return 'Password is required!';
              }
              return null;
            },
            cursorColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border:
                  OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
              labelText: 'Password',
              floatingLabelStyle: rubikMedium.copyWith(
                  color: isDarkMode
                      ? Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight
                      : Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              labelStyle: rubikMedium,
              fillColor: Colors.transparent,
              filled: true,
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: isDarkMode
                          ? Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight
                          : Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  passwordVisibility.value
                      ? Icons.visibility
                      : Icons.visibility_off,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  passwordVisibility.value = !passwordVisibility.value;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),

The text form field is not reset.
The ref.read working perfecly when Wrap it with Builder widget
